# Kummer's congruence at $p=3$

Tags: nt.number-theory, reference-request, co.combinatorics, analytic-number-theory, bernoulli-numbers

Let $B_{2k}$ be the [Bernoulli numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bernoulli_number) of even index and $\varphi(n)$ be [Euler's totient function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_totient_function). We recall one instance of [Kummer's congruences](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kummer%27s_congruence): for each integer $m\geq1$ and a prime number $p\geq5$, we have
$$(1-p)\frac{B_2}2\equiv (1-p^{\varphi(p^m)+1})\frac{B_{\varphi(p^m)+2}}{\varphi(p^m)+2} \pmod{p^m}. \tag1$$

If one tries to mimic (1) for the prime $p=3$, it would be that
$$(1-3)\frac{B_2}2\equiv (1-3^{\varphi(3^m)+1})\frac{B_{\varphi(3^m)+2}}{\varphi(3^m)+2} \pmod{3^m}$$
but it does not work. Similarly we may boost the index of Bernoulli and attempt with
$$(1-3)\frac{B_2}2\equiv (1-3^{6\varphi(3^m)+1})\frac{B_{6\varphi(3^m)+2}}{6\varphi(3^m)+2} \pmod{3^m}$$
which again fails. However, there seems to be a chance for the below formulation.

> **QUESTION.** Is this true? Numerical tests suggest so.
> $$(1-3)\frac{B_2}2\equiv (1-3^m)\frac{B_{6\varphi(3^m)+2}}{6\varphi(3^m)+2} \pmod{3^m}. \tag2$$

Answer (score 4):

This follows from the generalization of the Kummer congruences to the case
where $(p-1)\mid k$, which you can find as Proposition 11.4.4 of my GTM240
(I do not know if this is elsewhere in the literature). The complete statement
(from which a more precise version of your conjecture follows) is:

For any even $k\ge2$, set
$$z_p(k)=\begin{cases} (p^{k-1}-1)B_k/k 
\qquad \qquad \qquad \qquad \qquad \text{if $(p-1)\nmid k$} \\
(p^{k-1}-1)B_k/k+(1-1/p)/k 
\qquad \qquad \text{if $(p-1)\mid k$ and $p\ne3$} \\
(p^{k-1}-1)B_k/k+(1-1/p)/k-k \qquad \text{if $p=3$}.
\end{cases}$$
Then $z_p(k)$ is $p$-integral,
and if $k'\equiv k\pmod{\phi(p^m)}$ we have $z_p(k')\equiv z_p(k)\pmod{p^m}$.

You can then for instance apply this to $k=\phi(p^m)+2$ and $k'=2$.

Comment: Nice and thank you for the reference, I did not such a result elsewhere. Two questions: (1) your $k$ brings in a higher exponent $p^{\phi(p^m)+1}-1$ while I wish to have an exponent $p^m-1$ alongside $B_k/k$, so how do we do that?; (2) although we are computing mod $p^m$, for some reason the numerics forbid removing the factor $p^m-1$, why is that?